# Is there a way to expose SQL Server relational schema as REST API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET (Core) application, connected to a SQL Server 2016 instance. I would need to publish a generic REST API through which any data in the database relational schema could be queried from. I'm struggling to find any tool for this, which would either publish the schema through REST, or at least code generate an API from the database schema.

The application frontend of course consumes specific internal API:s, but this generic interface would be to enable publishing the whole schema for external applications.

Comment: Can you talk us through why you need to do this? What is the data in the database? Who are you exposing it to? Why do you need a REST API?

Comment: The client apparently has some internal application through which they would like to query all data. The database contains business transactional data. It is exposed only in internal network, to the client itself, not externally. REST API because we already publish some very specific REST API:s

Comment: Just a quick thought : you may find something with OData.

Comment: @GuillaumeRAYMOND thats not rest though

Comment: I think OData is still in Beta for .NET Core. Need to verify though... could there be other options to do this than REST though? In addition to OData...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OData together with EntityFramework core in an asp.net core application, it's still in Beta 2 but I am using it in a production application and works great (a few glitches but nothing really important).

You need to add the following NuGet references to your csproj file (if you use Visual Studio just use the NuGet package manager):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="7.0.0-beta2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.1" />
```

Then in your startup file, configure the services as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<YourEFDbContext>();
    services.AddOData();
    services.AddMvc(config => {
         config.Filters.Add(new EnableQueryAttribute() {
              PageSize = 100, //Default PageSize change to suit your needs
              //This is used to speficy how many levels of related classes you can expand in your queries
              MaxExpansionDepth = 3
            });
        });
 }
```

You also need to provide an Edm model with the entities and functionality you want to expose:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
    //Expose OData entities
    IEdmModel model = GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices);

    // This is use to define the route for your service, in this case it will be http://localhost:5000/someservice
    app.UseMvc(routeBuilder => routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "someservice", model));
 }

 private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
 {
     var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
     //Expose the entity Client and allow to filter, orderby, page, expand and select
     builder.EntitySet<Client>(nameof(Client)).EntityType.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Page().Expand(ExpandMaxDepth).Select();
     builder.EntitySet<Address>(nameof(Address)).EntityType.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Page().Expand(ExpandMaxDepth).Select();

     [...]

     return builder.GetEdmModel();
 }
```

Finally, for each entity of your model create a controller with the REST actions you would like to use:

```
public class ContactController
{
    private YourDbContext _db;

    public ContactController(YourDbContext db)
    {
         _db = db;
    }

    [EnableQuery()] //You don't actually need this because we added a filter in ConfigureServices
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //Always return an IQueryable
        return Ok(_db.Contacts.AsQueryable());
    }

    //Add PUT, PATCH and DELETE if needed...
}
```

Run your service and voila! You have exposed your entities through a rest webservice that can run on Windows, Linux and MacOS.

To try it out you can generate queries like this:

http://localhost:5000/Contact/?$filter=Name eq 'John'

http://localhost:5000/Contact/?$top=10&$skip=10

http://localhost:5000/Contact/?$expand=ContactAddress($filter=AddressId eq 1234)

And many more, see here for more info: http://www.odata.org/

**Edit**

What's the difference between odata and creating your own WebApi controllers? The main advantage over a WebApi controller is that odata supports queryables, for example, you can have a grid in your client that automatically calls your server and uses linq to make a query just like if it was connected directly to the database. Here is more info:

http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2014/09/12/10-OData-FAQs  https://www.progress.com/blogs/odata-faqs-why-should-rest-api-developers-use-odata

Comment: Thanks Isma for the thorough post :) one question though, I see you anyway need to create a controller per entity, so OData does not generate these for you? What convenience does OData then add to this? Wouldn't it be the same to just create a WebApi controller for each entity?